# How to redirect this url with .htaccess a specific url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, permanent

How to redirect this url with .htaccess

http://www.example.com/products.php?IDZ=0-0-0-106-1&start=156

to

http://www.example.com/

301 permanent redirection

Comment: Have you not tried anything? Providing information about your attempts is useful to finding an answer. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on asking questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/products\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^IDZ=(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^IDZ=(.*)&start=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/? [R=302,L]
```

I solved the issue this may be helpful for other people